# Reusable code to make rectangle opacity zero on double-tap

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have some rectangles that I want to make "appear" when you double-tap the screen where they are:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Rectangle Name="MyRect1" Opacity="0" Height="100" DoubleTapped="MyRect1_DoubleTapped" Fill="Aqua" />
    <Rectangle Name="MyRect2" Opacity="0" Height="100" DoubleTapped="MyRect2_DoubleTapped" Fill="Black"/>
    <Rectangle Name="MyRect3" Opacity="0" Height="100" DoubleTapped="MyRect3_DoubleTapped" Fill="Blue"/>
</StackPanel>
```

My current code behind - this works:

```
private void MyRect1_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyRect1.Opacity = 1;
}

private void MyRect2_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyRect2.Opacity = 1;
}

private void MyRect3_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyRect3.Opacity = 1;
}
```

Since I may want a dozen or more of these appearing rectangles, is there any way to just use the one event handler for all of them?

i.e. instead of having a handler for each rectangle, have something like:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Rectangle Name="MyRect1" Opacity="0" Height="100" DoubleTapped="MyRect_DoubleTapped" Fill="Aqua" />
    <Rectangle Name="MyRect2" Opacity="0" Height="100" DoubleTapped="MyRect_DoubleTapped" Fill="Black"/>
    <Rectangle Name="MyRect3" Opacity="0" Height="100" DoubleTapped="MyRect_DoubleTapped" Fill="Blue"/>
</StackPanel>
```

With a single handler `MyRect_DoubleTapped`:

```
private void MyRect_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (some way to tell which rectangle was DoubleTapped)
    (the identified rectangle).Opacity = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `sender` to know which one was tapped

```
private void MyRect_DoubleTapped(object sender, DoubleTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle myRect = (Rectangle)sender;
    myRect.Opacity = 1;
}
```

The `sender` is the object that raised the event.

Comment: Just had to add "using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes;" (as suggested by VS) and it's working as required. Cheers!